# MySQL Output column based on value that corresponds with max ID

Tags: mysql, max

There are a lot of questions dealing with max values but I can't find any that relate to this issue.

```
ID | Company | Result
----------------------
1  |    1    |   A
2  |    1    |   C
3  |    1    |   B <--
4  |    2    |   C
5  |    2    |   B
6  |    2    |   A <!--
7  |    3    |   C
8  |    3    |   A
9  |    3    |   B <--
```

I need to output the Companies whose last Result (based on ID) was "B".

To further complicate the issue, the $query will be used this:

`select * from table where Company in ($query)`

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column It's like this 

SELECT Company, MAX(ID)
FROM YourTable
WHERE Result = "B"
GROUP BY Company

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen As long as the ID column is set to auto-increment, that should get the latest record. The result should have the ID of the record and the ID of the company.

Comment: @ihodonald The logic is incorrect, because `WHERE` happens _before_ `GROUP BY`.  This means that your query would also return `(5, 2, B)` from the sample data above.

Comment: @ihodonald the ID is set to AI.  But your suggestion would include Company 2 in the example above, since B is one of their Results... just not the last Result.  The output to the example should only return Company 1 & 3... which are the two Companies whose last Result was B.

Comment: J-- Ah, yes. That may require another query to see what the maximum ID is on a record for that company. Or, you could just use the inner join from @TimBiegeleisen's answer. My apologies. It's been a while since I've used SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MySQL 8+, here is a query you may try using analytic functions:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Company ORDER BY ID DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT ID, Company, Result
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1 AND Result = 'B';
```

### Demo

On earlier versions of MySQL, we can try joining to a subquery which finds the most recent record for each company:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Company, MAX(ID) AS MAX_ID
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Company
) t2
    ON t1.Company = t2.Company AND
       t1.ID = t2.MAX_ID
WHERE
    t1.Result = 'B';
```

### Demo

Comment: The first one is a bit out of my league... and not sure it would be fit inside a ```select * from table where Company in (________)``` kind of query.  But the 2nd one is it!!  I did have to change the ```t1.*``` to ```t1.Company``` so it would only output the just Company to fit in the blank above... but that's it!!  Thank you!!